# Content Search Web Part: Search Fields

Tags: 2013, search, kql

I'm having some trouble querying fields with KQL.  I have a custom list with a field named "A".

The following query returns results:

```
path:"<My URL>"  (  title:"<Text that Appears in title>")
```

This query does not return results

```
path:"<My URL>"  (  A:"<Text that Appears in A>")
```

I imagine that I have to set up crawling or I'm using the wrong type of field.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a Managed Property for "A"? If not your query will not work. If "A" was created as a Site Column, SharePoint will create an "Automatic" Managed Property based on the name and data type. For example, if "A" is of type TEXT you could try `AOWSTEXT:"Text in A"`

There are tons of examples on how to create Managed Properties if you search for it.